# Import data from Excel into SQL Server CE

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server-ce

I am using SQL Server CE ToolBox for working with SQL Server CE databases (`.sdf` file).

What should be my approach to import Excel data into a SQL Server CE database?

Is this possible through C# code??

Answer (score 0):

SQLCE Toolbox is able to import data from csv file, so just export your excel data to that format and use it to load the data into your sql ce database.

Comment: Can you provide me a link to that as I cant find any options which import data from csv.

Comment: A link? Right-click on your table and select "Import data from CSV"

Comment: The Toolbox is open source C# code, and uses my scripting api + the kbcsv library for cvs import, so yes